# Pie style progress bar with CSS3?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, pie-chart

Are there any libraries or examples how to create pie style progress bars with CSS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas or SVG would be a better fit than CSS for this. (Due to lack of circle segments). [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) might be a good choice if you go for SVG. Here's a [(non-animated) pie chart](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html), which will show you how to draw segments.

Answer (score 1):

another great choice for SVG based graphs is [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).  It is the successor to the Protovis library, but is much more flexible and much better written (and thus better preforming).  Also, you can style some properties of SVG elements with CSS3, but not as much as you can style HTML.  However, CSS is still useful, and you can still, for example, use transitions on some properties.  Take a look at the W3C's [Styling SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html) document (although be aware that it just discusses CSS2).

Answer (score 1):

Pie chart [is possible](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/uploader/images/css3-designs/css3-charts/index.html#q3_2009) in pure css but animating it may not be easy.